# Handling touch-based events

Tags: javascript, touch

I currently have this for my touch events:

```
if( 'ontouchstart' in document.body) {
    usevkeys = true;
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart",function(e) {evt.call(this,e);},false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchend",function(e) {evt.call(this,e);},false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove",function(e) {evt.call(this,e);},false);
}
else {
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e) {evt.call(this,e);},false);
    canvas.addEventListener("click",function(e) {evt.call(this,e);},false);
}
```

This works fine on my laptop, and on my phone. However, I have to wonder, how would this react in an environment that has both a touchscreen and a normal mouse? Does the mouse trigger touch events, like the phone triggers `mousemove` events?

What can I do to make sure it works?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but Modernizr uses `if(('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch) {`. I wonder if that helps narrow it down? As I re-read your question, I'm not sure I'm answering/helping anything.

Comment: What if you got rid of the `else {` and `}`, and just left it so the `mousemove` and `click` events are always bound? That way, if there's touch events, those are bound, but the normal mouse events are always bound. If they touch the screen, the touch events occur, otherwise mouse events occur. Or do some of the events overlap? Such as the `touchmove` and `mousemove` events?

Comment: I experienced that although touch events are supported mouse events can occur (without touch events) if an USB mouse is used (might be depending on the OS). I always went for: observe both and unset mouse event listener when touchstart is firing for the first time... this saves unneeded event listeners and gives you the control

Answer (score 0):

a `touchstart` triggers the `click` event as soon as `touchend` has fired (-> if it hasn't been canceled). So you should just remove the else clause and should be fine!

Microsoft went a different way with their touch events in IE10 to harmonize all pointer-devices into [Pointer and gesture events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where you can check if it has been fired by a mouse, pen or a finger - or perhaps a kinect-style device in the future.

Comment: Well, that's what I tried originally. Problem is, though, my phone would trigger `mousemove` events with odd results, causing flickering and making it unusable.

Comment: try attaching the mousemove/touchmove event within the click/touchstart function. I'd like to opensrc my code, but I aint allowed, sorry.

Comment: That still wouldn't do much good, since the phone will fire a `click` event on the first click-like touch, and then subsequent touches will be buggy.