# Using click() on links in Android Stock Browser not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to trigger a click on a link with JavaScript but have problems getting it to work on the Android Stock Browser. The following code works fine in Chrome (Desktop, Mac) and Safari (iOS) but not in the Android Stock Browser (Samsung Galaxy S3):

```
<a href="test" id="a">One</a>
<a href="test" id="b">Two</a>

<script>
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('b').click();
});

document.getElementById('b').addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("test");
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xYfdF/7/

When replacing the links with buttons it starts working on Android as well: http://jsfiddle.net/xYfdF/8/

Any idea what the problem is or how to achieve this otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/commit/ef2e880d40eb81636ba052f04ae5719e8526567a). Its pure JS, not jquery, but might help to solve missing `click()` on android stock browsers:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" id="link">click here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //same as: document.getElementById("link").click()
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    clickEvent.initEvent('click', true, true);
    document.getElementById("link").dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert your click events to touch events using Jquery like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    {
       jQuery('#a').bind("touchstart touchend touchmove click",function(event) 
       {
    event.preventDefault();
         jQuery('#b').click();
       });

      jQuery('#b').bind("touchstart touchend touchmove click",function(event) 
       {
    event.preventDefault();
         alert('Test');
       });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not possible to use jQuery since it's on a script that will be embedded on customers' websites. I will look into using touch events though.

Comment: see this link if useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552822/handling-touch-based-events