# Android Browser .click() not working javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to click a button programmatically with javascript. Using the following code works fine:

```
var pbutton= document.getElementById('psubmit');
pbutton.click();
```

but when I try it on my mobile browser it wont fire the click event.  Is their another way to do this for Mobile Browsers?

Comment: If you don't mind using some jQuery you can try using `$("#psubmit").trigger("click");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using click() on links in Android Stock Browser not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936066/using-click-on-links-in-android-stock-browser-not-working)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement jquery for this or use a simple javascript.

You can add following code to implement through pure javascript

```
document.getElementById('psubmit').click();
```

You can check jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5movtwzj/)

or for jquery you can implement by

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(){ alert("JQuery Running!");});
 $( "#btn" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

You can check jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f4he2y9d/)

For both this to work you need to have id property defined. And to implement jquery you will need to add jquery file in you code. Hope this helps. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('#psubmit').click()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery:

```
$('psubmit').live("click",function(){
     //Function code here
});
```